# Calculating circumference of circle using method

Tags: java, math, methods

It may be rather simple but I am having issues returning a value for "circum" here is my code.

```
double circRad = 0;
double circum = 0;

if(userOption == 2){

        circRad = myRad();
        System.out.println("The Radius of the circle is " + circRad + " and it perimeter is "+ circum);

public static double myRad(){

    int i= 1;
    double circRad = 0;
    Scanner myInput=new Scanner(System.in);

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive Radius for the circle ");
        circRad = myInput.nextDouble();
        while(circRad <0){
            System.out.print("Please enter a POSITIVE Radius for the circle ");
            circRad = myInput.nextDouble();
            }
                ++i;
    }
    return circRad;
}

public static double myRad(double circRad){

    double circum = 0;

    circum = 2* Math.PI * circRad;

    return circum;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: You initialized circum as 0 but did not put the value of circRad comes from myRad(). Add this before you output the radius and perimeter:
"circum = myRad(circRad);"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing the following:

```
if(userOption == 2){
    circRad = myRad();
    circum  = myRad(circRad); // <-- missing setting local circum value
    System.out.println("The Radius of the circle is " + circRad + " and it perimeter is "+ circum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I could guess about the code with the way it is presented is that `circRad` and `circum` are global variables, therefore when you call the first `myRad()` only circRad changes. However, `circum` remains 0.
If you could sent the entire code, it'll make everything easier.